# How to extract request url using python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, url, web-scraping, web-inspector

I am new to webscraping and need some help to extract a `request-url` from the online movie-stream website [YIFY](http://yify.tv/watch-the-revenant-online-free-yify/). I am familiar with how selenium works and I am trying to find the download `url` of the movie [`Revenant`](http://yify.tv/watch-the-revenant-online-free-yify/).

Using `python-selenium` I can click on the play icon and if you open your `inspect element` and go the `network` tab then you can see the `request-url` but you can't do inspect element and find it.

[image]

Download link - `http://download1282.mediafire.com/3pvv1jx9z23g/crdad7bg0ghjh7r/vid.pdf`

I am trying to extract this particular download link using `python-selenium`. Could anyone tell me if it is possible? Well I am not trying to download the movie but checking if it is possible to download the links from it. Here the links are not embedded in the html page, and I will highly appreciate any help.

Comment: Are you trying to download a link or a file? Can you show us the HTML tag that the link/file is in?

Comment: Only link but the hard part is there is no HTML tag for it. Video is not embedded here